# Trouble with VB6 form location (top,left) and value type (i.e., integer)

Tags: forms, vb6, location, multiple-monitors

VB6 will REPORT a LEFT location greater than max integer when the form is in an auxiliary screen.  However, I cannot assign that value as a LEFT specification.

1. I manually drag frmSecondary to the secondary monitor (located to the right of my primary monitor).
2. I click a button within frmSecondary in order to write the value of frmSeconday.Left to a file.  It writes 49950.
3. I close the program, then re-open.
4. I read the value from the file (and the value IS 49950).
5. I try to programmatically assign that value to frmSecondary.Left
6. Failure (works OK if the value is less than "largest integer").

Expected result:  I should be able to assign the value that was written to file.  Better yet, any ideas of how to programmatically place frmSecondary at it's "proper" location on the secondary monitor?

I simply read the value from file:

```
 Input #fnum, frmSecondary.left
```

I've tried, without success:

```
 Dim lft as variant

 Input #fnum, lft

 frmSecondary.left = lft
```

I have confirmed that the value being read from file is, in fact, 49950.  I do this confirmation two ways...one is by looking at the file; the second is by putting a "stop" in the program and showing the value of lft.

TOTAL NONSENSE

Ignore this entire post.  I just discovered my error -- it's so embarrassing, I don't even want to describe it.  Nothing quite like spending an entire afternoon (to say nothing of YOUR time) chasing garbage.

Comment: Show the code that tries to set the Form Left property.  It should be fine getting assigned 49950 because Left is a Single not an Integer.

Comment: As @tcarvin states, form Left and Top properties are not integers.  See the VB6 language reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa235144(v=vs.60).  The form Height and Width properties are also of type Single, not Integer.

Comment: 1. Variants are evil, always use the datatype that you intend to be working with 2. What happens if you change that line to `frmSecondary.left = 49950` (just to rule out any data input issues)  3. You don't state what "Failure" means.  What is the actual error code that is happening?